# Distribute a number evenly between bins

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Take a number **N** and distribute it as evenly as possible among **i** bins.
i.e. For **N** distributed across **i** bins as [N<sub>1</sub>,N<sub>2</sub>....N<sub>i</sub>], Σ(N<sub>a</sub> - N<sub>b</sub>) is minimized for all a,b ∈ {0,1,..i}

I have to do this in Python. I have come up with a simplistic approach till now that works as follows:

- Initial size of each bin is N/i (integer division)
- Keep adding 1 to each bin in sequence from the remainder of the integer division till the remainder is exhausted.

Code:

```
def eq_div(N,x):
    a = [N/x for i in range(x)]
    rem = N%x

    def eq_map(val):
        global rem
        if rem > 0:
            rem -= 1
            return val + 1
        else:
            return val

    return map(eq_map, a)
```

This works but it uses the ungainly `global` keyword. Am I missing a library function that does this? Or can I do the same without using global?
Is there a different better solution?

Comment: you don't need the global in this code snippet, just remove it.

Comment: Removing that will cause an `UnboundLocalError` to be thrown because `rem` will be referenced before assignment.

Comment: Doh, my fault, it is because you are changing the variable below... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just loop and add 1 to each of the first rem elements of a.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt :)  I think it's much simpler and more readable than the original and therefore easier to maintain.  (I'm bigotted against functional programming, ymmv).

```
def pidgeon_hole(n, n_bins): 
    quotient = n // n_bins
    remainder = n % n_bins

    bins = [quotient for i in range(n_bins)]    
    for i in range(remainder):
        bins[i] += 1
    return bins


bins = pidgeon_hole(13, 3)
for bin in bins: 
    print(bin)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.x / Python 3.x:

```
def eq_div(N, i):
    return [] if i <= 0 else [N // i + 1] * (N % i) + [N // i] * (i - N % i)

>>> eq_div(-10, 3)
[-3, -3, -4]
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nonlocal instead of global in  this case.

Comment: No nonlocal in 2.7 sadly.